# when is jQuery UI's destroy() called?

Tags: jquery-ui, widget, destroy

I get that when developing a jQuery UI widget one must override destroy and call super.destroy or destroy on any nested widgets. But when is/should destroy be called? Is it ever being called auto-magically by jQueryUI framework? Or should it be called by a client programmer (using my awesome widget)?

For example, say I have a lightbox (fancybox) that displays an accordion(). Say the accordion is being created in fancybox' onStart callback - as the lightbox is about to be displayed.
Should accordion('destroy') be called in 'on-lightbox-close' callback? Seems unnecessary...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`destroy` is called by *you* when you want to destroy the widget.

It is also called by UI when you `.remove()` an element from the DOM which had been "widgetized."

As for your specific use case, it depends.  Will the same lightbox instance be re-opened at any point in the future of that page-load's lifetime?  If so, destroying would only add overhead as the next showing of the lightbox would require a "re-widgetization". If not, then not destroying would leave memory being taken up for no reason. (this assumes that the close of your lightbox does not cause the elements to be removed from the DOM)

Comment: Any proof that jquery UI calles destroy if an element gets removed? I'm curious if they really do this, and if so, how.

Comment: Frug - override _destroy in your widget and set a breakpoint.  You'll see it get called.